# Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference for textbox autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to search company names using jquery. If search parameter does not exists in employee list, it should returns all companies. When I put breakpoint to GetCompanyList, it could not hit. But I am getting  JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
How can I solve this error? By the way I have no idea Javascript. I have just used it for my project. Thanks your help

```
Demo.aspx.cs
public partial class Demo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static List<string> allCompanyName = new List<string>() { "ankara", "adana", "istanbul" };
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<string> GetCompanyName(string pre)
    {
        var response = allCompanyName.Any(i => i.StartsWith(pre));
        return allCompanyName;
    }
}
```

```
Demo.aspx

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Demo.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=txtCompanyName.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "Demo.aspx/GetCompanyName",
            data: "{ 'pre':'" + request.term + "'}",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                    return { value: item }
                }))
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <h3>Auto Complete Textbox without using Web Service</h3>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Type Company Name: </td>
        <td>
            <div class="ui-widget" style="text-align:left">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server" Width="350px" CssClass="textboxAuto"  Font-Size="12px" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error happen if you call `$.map` on null instead of array check `$.map(null, function(x) { return x + 1; })` in console.

Comment: so debug `success: function (data) { console.log("data.d", data.d); console.log("data", data);` and see what the server is actually returning